# Adding Info Boxes to a Mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have another "mindmap" related question. I modified an example off of [texample.net](http://www.texample.net) to get the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Information Boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][16.3]{%
  \node [ annotation, #3, scale=0.9, text width = #1em,
          inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
  \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
    \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
    \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
    #4
  \endlist
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] (CORE) {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] (AI) {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Theory) {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Systems) {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Games) {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (SE) {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (IT) {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
    \info{CORE.north east}{above,yshift=2em}{
      \item Mathematical Foundations
      \item Imperative Programming
      \item Introduction to Algorithms
      \item Data Structures
      \item Systems Programming
      \item Theory of Computation
      \item Intro to Computer Architecture
    }
    \info{IT.north east}{right}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Programming on the Internet
      \item Advanced Java Programming
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{AI.north east}{above}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Natural Language Processing
      \item Introduction to AI
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Theory.north east}{right}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Graph Theory
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Systems.north east}{above}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Operating Systems
      \item Advanced Computer Architecture
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Games.north east}{above}{
      \item Intro to Game Programming
      \item Advanced Game Programming
      \item Computer Graphics
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{SE.north east}{right}{
      \item Software Engineering
      \item Software Carpentry
      \item \dots
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: initial mindmap]

This is all well and good, but I'd like to modify the info boxes to be both outlined and centered closer to their respective nodes. For example, for Software Engineering and Internet Technologies I'd like the info boxes to be centered immediately above the respective nodes, while Theory and Systems would be centered immediately below. AI and Game Programming would be centered to the right and left respectively.

I tried drawing boxes around the info boxes with the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Information Boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][16.3]{%
  \node [ annotation, #3, scale=0.9, text width = #1em,
          inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
  \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
    \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
    \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
    #4
  \endlist
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every annotation/.style = {draw,fill=white}]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] (CORE) {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] (AI) {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Theory) {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Systems) {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Games) {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (SE) {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (IT) {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
    \info{CORE.north east}{above,yshift=2em}{
      \item Mathematical Foundations
      \item Imperative Programming
      \item Introduction to Algorithms
      \item Data Structures
      \item Systems Programming
      \item Theory of Computation
      \item Intro to Computer Architecture
    }
    \info{IT.north east}{right}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Programming on the Internet
      \item Advanced Java Programming
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{AI.north east}{above}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Natural Language Processing
      \item Introduction to AI
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Theory.north east}{right}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Graph Theory
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Systems.north east}{above}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Operating Systems
      \item Advanced Computer Architecture
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Games.north east}{above}{
      \item Intro to Game Programming
      \item Advanced Game Programming
      \item Computer Graphics
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{SE.north east}{right}{
      \item Software Engineering
      \item Software Carpentry
      \item \dots
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this produces nodes that are far too wide and overlap the primary graphic:

[image]

How can I fix both the overly wide box outlines and the info box positioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! You could just use the fact that you can use angles for the anchors and feed the relative positions like `above` with positive or negative distances, make the annotations `text width` smaller and not draw their boundaries.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Information Boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][7]{%
  \node [ annotation, scale=0.9, text width = #1em, #3,
          inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
  \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
    \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
    \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
    #4
  \endlist
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every annotation/.style = {draw=none}]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] (CORE) {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] (AI) {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Theory) {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Systems) {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Games) {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (SE) {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (IT) {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
    \info{IT.165}{anchor=north east,xshift=1.5em}{
      \item Mathematical Foundations
      \item Imperative Programming
      \item Introduction to Algorithms
      \item Data Structures
      \item Systems Programming
      \item Theory of Computation
      \item Intro to Computer Architecture
    }
    \info{IT.north east}{right}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Programming on the Internet
      \item Advanced Java Programming
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{AI.north east}{above=1ex}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Natural Language Processing
      \item Introduction to AI
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Theory.north east}{right}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Graph Theory
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Systems.north}{above left=-1.5em}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Operating Systems
      \item Advanced Computer Architecture
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Games.north east}{above=1ex}{
      \item Intro to Game Programming
      \item Advanced Game Programming
      \item Computer Graphics
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{SE.north east}{right}{
      \item Software Engineering
      \item Software Carpentry
      \item \dots
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need to add boxes around the annotations, you can do that, but IMHO this does not look as good.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% Font Settings

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,babel,final]{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

% Information Boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][7]{%
  \node [ annotation, scale=0.9, text width = #1em, #3,
          inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
  \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
    \parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
    \itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
    #4
  \endlist
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every annotation/.style = {draw,fill=white}]
  \path[mindmap,concept color=Gainsboro,text=Black]
    node[concept] (CORE) {CS Core}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child[concept] { node[concept] (AI) {AI Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Theory) {Theory Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Systems) {Systems Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (Games) {Game Programming Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (SE) {Software Engineering Track} }
    child[concept] { node[concept] (IT) {Internet Technologies Track} }
    ;
    \info{IT.165}{anchor=north east,xshift=0.2em}{
      \item Mathematical Foundations
      \item Imperative Programming
      \item Introduction to Algorithms
      \item Data Structures
      \item Systems Programming
      \item Theory of Computation
      \item Intro to Computer Architecture
    }
    \info{IT.north east}{right=1em}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Programming on the Internet
      \item Advanced Java Programming
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{AI.north east}{above=2ex}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Natural Language Processing
      \item Introduction to AI
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Theory.north east}{right=1ex}{
      \item Concepts of Programming Languages
      \item Graph Theory
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Systems.north}{above left}{
      \item Computer Networks
      \item Operating Systems
      \item Advanced Computer Architecture
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{Games.north east}{above=2ex}{
      \item Intro to Game Programming
      \item Advanced Game Programming
      \item Computer Graphics
      \item \dots
    }
    \info{SE.north east}{above right}{
      \item Software Engineering
      \item Software Carpentry
      \item \dots
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but what if I do want the outlines around the info boxes?